# how many boquets of 10 flowers can you make with 4 types of flowers

Tags: combinatorics

How many boquets of 10 flowers can you make with 4 types of flowers?
Tough one. I heard using "stars and bars" is the approach, but still don't get it.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine a boquet, take a row $10+4-1$ empty symbols$\dots$
$$
\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,
$$
choose $4-1$ of them to be bars$\dots$
$$
\_\,\_\,|\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,|\,|\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,
$$
and the rest to be $\star$'s:
$$
\star\,\star\,|\,\star\,\star\,\star\,\star\,|\,|\,\star\,\star\,\star\,\star\,
$$
The number of flowers of each type is the number of stars in each space between bars. In the above example, there will be 2 flowers of the first type, 4 of the second, 0 of third, 4 of fourth. This shows that choosing a bouquet is the same as choosing $3$ elements from a set of $13$, so the number of boquets is $\binom{13}{3}$.

Comment: interesting concept